# How to see the changes in the graph editor while rotating an object

Tags: animation, keyframes, graph-editor

Is there a possibility to see the changes in the graph editor while rotating an object (a keyframe in a curve changes its height) i.e. not when the object is already keyframed, but when you're still able to change its rotation?

Comment: What is the actual Blender bigger goal of having such data?

Comment: You can change object's rotation even if it's keyframed, the changes only won't be saved. If the object isn't keyframed yet, it won't have any data in Graph Editor / anywhere, hence no changes won't be detected.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger It'll be more convenient to adjust some keyframes (by rotating the object) while you see its instant changes in the graph editor. I've used to change the keyframes directly in the graph editor, but I've heard I shouldn't do it since I use Quaternion rotation. Hence, the W rotation doesn't change automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph editor displays keyframed values. If you haven't keyframed a value then the graph editor doesn't have any data to display.

Similarly, as you move an object in the 3DView you are not altering any keyframed data so there are no changes being made to the data displayed in the graph editor.

Note that it does work the other way. After keyframing a value you can make adjusts in the graph editor and see the changes in the 3DView as you make them.

Comment: But if I adjust the keyframes in the graph editor the W rotation wouldn't be automatically adjusted. Isn't that bad?

Comment: @Eti2d1 it sounds like you need a better understanding of euler vs. quaternion rotation. When you rotate something on X it doesn't rotate Y automatically is correct and applies to both rotation types. Checkout Nathan Vegdahl's [video on the subject](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4mXL751ko0w).